# Installing apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip (can't set file paths properly)

Tags: java, windows, maven

I saw there are plenty of guides but I still can't seem to make it work.

- I downloaded from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi the file apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip
- I placed it in C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4
- JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1
- M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4
- MAVEN_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4

**I am still getting an error:**

" 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. "

What am I doing wrong?

[image: environment paths pic]

Comment: Nothing else than the entry in `PATH` is needed. No `M2_HOME` and no `MAVEN_HOME` is needed. After you changed the `PATH` variable you have to reopen a console to get change working

Answer (score 2):

You need to add maven's bin folder to your `PATH` so it can find the `mvn` executable. I.e., add `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` to the `PATH` variable, launch a new terminal, and you should be OK.